# xcopy in Windows x64 : File not found

Tags: windows, xcopy, batch-file

This script to copy All file and folder in `%programfiles%` or `%programfiles(x86)` to destination folder. if my windows architecture x86, copy `%programfiles%`, copying file/folder successful, but not if my windows architecture x64.

**Script**

```
@echo Off

set Arch=x64
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" ( 
    if not defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 set Arch=x86
) 

echo Arsitektur Prosesor Windows Anda %Arch%
set /P drive=Folder backup akan disimpan di drive apa : %=% 
if %Arch% == "x64"  (
    if not exist "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\C" mkdir "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\C"
    if not exist "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\VIRTUALSTORE" mkdir "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\VIRTUALSTORE"
     xcopy /Y /S "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\DJP\*.*" "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\C"
    xcopy /Y /S "%localappdata%\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\DJP\*.*" "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\VIRTUALSTORE"
) else  (
    if not exist "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\C" mkdir "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\C"
    if not exist "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\VIRTUALSTORE" mkdir "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\VIRTUALSTORE"
    xcopy /y /S "%ProgramFiles%\DJP\*.*" "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\C"
    xcopy /y /S "%localappdata%\VirtualStore\Program Files\DJP\*.*" "%drive%:\BACKUP_ESPT\VIRTUALSTORE"

)


ECHO Proses Backup e-SPT selesai
pause
```

**Result**

```
Arsitektur Prosesor Windows Anda x64
Folder backup akan disimpan di drive apa :  D
File not found - *.*
0 File(s) copied
File not found - *.*
0 File(s) copied
Proses Backup e-SPT selesai
Press any key to continue . . .
```

what's wrong? correct me please. thanks

Comment: The first troubleshooting step is to leave out the "echo off" line so that you can see what the script is actually doing.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your script?

Comment: Er, yeah, `@echo Off` makes your life really difficult!!

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at your script, and correct me if I am wrong, but when the processor architecture is x64, then you're accessing the x86 folders (as in your case). Is that what you want?

By the way: you are using the /s option for xcopy. That is the option to copy entire directories. You don't need the `*.*` postfix then: just specify the directory and it'll copy it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if %Arch% == "x64"  (
```

should be

```
if "%Arch%"=="x64"  (
```

A string-match is absolutely literal; `x64` and `"x64"` are not the same thing, so the `else` branch would be taken and the targets don't exist.